# How to solve error : finished with non-zero exit value 1 in spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

[System]
Spring boot: 2.1.7 Release
Gradle: 4.10.2

I usually know that the above error appears when the port number is being used by another program, but the error also occurs when I change the port.
As expected, the error occurs by an Apache Poi added at Gradle dependencies.
I want to know the method that solves this problem.
Below is my Gradle code.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.7.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group 'com.tistory.cafecoder'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('com.h2database:h2')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mustache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client:')
    compile('org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.11')
    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Comment: Apache POI added you your dependencies has *nothing* to do with port conflict

Comment: I think there have been no problems so far, and I have habitually shut down the server. Since the problem occurred after adding the Apache POI dependency, I wondered if there was a problem with this. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
The POI itself was not a problem. I didn't want to solve everything in the service class, so I declared an outer class to parse the xlsx file.
I used @RequiredArgsConstructor.
In the process, I encountered a problem by declaring a simple class as "personal final".
It was simply a matter of lack of knowledge of Spring Boot annotations.... TT